# inserting into database using post method in android

Tags: php, android, http-post

I have a register form in android application. i want to need insert this registration information into web database so that after registration i can login by verifying the database which is stored.

my onPostExecute method is

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            if(result.equals("working")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "HTTP POST is working...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid POST req...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

and my php code is

```
$varUsername = $_POST['paramUsername'];
$varPassword = $_POST['paramPassword'];

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') 
 {

    $con= mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
     if (!$con) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
                    }

      // make foo the current db
     $db_selected = mysql_select_db('post_db', $con);
       if (!$db_selected) {   die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());}


     $sql="INSERT INTO post_table (username,password)
       VALUES('$varUsername ','$varPassword')";

       if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){ die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con)); }

echo 'working';

     }
            else{
                echo 'invalid';
                       }
```

But my information can't be inserted. It always show the toast of "  Invalid POST req...";
What should i do to insert the registration information into the web database??
And after that what should be the procedure for login???

Comment: Maybe try to narrow down what's broken. I would start by commenting out all the PHP script to just be `echo 'working';`. Then if the toast still says 'Invalid', your problem is somewhere in `doInBackground()`. If it says 'is working', then your problem is in the PHP.

Comment: i did so and worked fine .